# How to get a more declarative string for VBScript errors

Tags: delphi, winapi, com, activex

Just to explain more about the context, this is how to reproduce:

- Delphi 7 (but perhaps more recent versions as well)
- Import Type Library "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

Write a program around this code:

```
var
  re:RegExp;
try
  re:=CoRegExp.Create;
  re.Pattern:='(';//is an invalid regex, but see below
  re.Test('');
except
  on e:Exception do
    Caption:=e.ClassName+' '+e.Message;
end;
```

This will throw an Exception `EOleError OLE error 800A139C`

It does so because SysErrorMessage returns an empty string on this code and the EOleSysError constructor defaults to the SOleError resource string to return something.

Is there a winapi alternative to SysErrorMessage to get a hold of a better error description? If I google around a bit, the code does stand for a 'missing parentheses' error, but if there is a way I could get a (localized) description from the system, I would prefer using it, over having to add an enumeration of error-description constants to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [COM error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx). To get a textual description call [GetErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then [IErrorInfo.GetDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But don't be surprised if you don't get anything useful back.

Comment: That entirely depends on the COM object's implementation.  Not all COM objects support the `IErrorInfo` interface, but many do.  If you use the `safecall` calling convention to call the COM object methods, then Delphi automatically calls `GetErrorInfo()` and raises an `EOleException` that contains the extra error values from `IErrorInfo`.

Comment: I've debugged and ComObj.pas' SafeCallError does indeed call GetErrorInfo, but doesn't return S_OK. I'm specifically asking for VBScript_RegExp_55_TLB, but for now it looks like it doesn't support IErrorInfo. Still a decent answer to my question so I'll accept.